# Nexus 5 Update To Android 5.1

Tags: nexus-5, twrp, 5.1-lollipop

When I try to download the OTA for 5.1 it gets stuck at "Waiting to download". Am I the only one that has this problem or is there a fix? Also, **if**
I manage to download it, will I be able to update or will TWRP get in the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the update, I have to reboot my phone a few times.

To *install* the update however, I will need to unroot (to get the stock recovery), install the update (after downloading it you get the option to install) and then re-root my phone (not necessary but if you're like me, you will want to).